# How to access properties of nested query with neo4j apoc.convert.toTree()?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using apoc.convert.toTree  query

```
MATCH path = (e:Elections)<-[OF_ELECTION]-(r:Race)<-[c:ISA_CANDIDATE]-
```

(m:Member)  WITH collect(path) as paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths) yield value
RETURN  value

to return a nested array like this:

```
{
  "election_date": "2022-06-01",
  "campaign_end": "2022-05-20",
  "certify_authorization": [
    "General Secretary"
  ],
  "election_start_time": "00:00:00-04:00",
  "nomination_end": "2022-05-17",
  "_type": "Elections",
  "of_election": [
    {
      "race_id": "d9f7164b-c7b5-4ce5-a100-989e99100912",
      "_type": "Race",
      "name": "Chairperson",
      "rank": 1,
      "_id": 18,
      "isa_candidate": [
        {
          "member_id": "397a2303-5030-4686-8bf6-25adc7fde33b",
          "role": "admin",
          "isa_candidate.createdAt": "2022-06-28",
          "created": "2022-06-12",
          "_type": "Member",
          "last_name": "Meek",
          "telephone": "8763719683",
          "middle_name": "X",
          "trn": "108859525",
          "assocition": "Hill Top Primary",
          "isa_candidate.url": "/assets/manifestos/397a2303-5030-4686-8bf6-25adc7fde33b-d9f7164b-c7b5-4ce5-a100-989e99100912.pdf",
          "isa_candidate.certified": true,
          "member_status": "full",
          "how_paid": "MOE",
          "paid_up": true,
          "_id": 1147,
          "category": "full",
          "isa_candidate.manifesto_summary": "This is my Summary...",
          "first_name": "Devon",
          "email": "meekyd2015@yahoo.com",
          "status": "active"
        },
        {
          "member_id": "7c2d7d7b-4a8f-4bff-854d-c09afe78f535",
          "role": "admin",
          "isa_candidate.createdAt": "2022-06-28",
          "created": "2022-06-12",
          "_type": "Member",
          "last_name": "Meeks-Ellis",
          "telephone": "8764543719",
          "middle_name": "Lorraine",
          "trn": "101472161",
          "assocition": "Hill Top Primary",
          "isa_candidate.url": "/assets/manifestos/7c2d7d7b-4a8f-4bff-854d-c09afe78f535-d9f7164b-c7b5-4ce5-a100-989e99100912.pdf",
          "isa_candidate.certified": true,
          "member_status": "full",
          "how_paid": "MOE",
          "paid_up": true,
          "_id": 1152,
          "category": "full",
          "isa_candidate.manifesto_summary": "This is my Summary...",
          "first_name": "Faithilyn",
          "email": "faithilyn.meeksellis@jta.org.jm",
          "status": "active"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "race_id": "256c2ac2-114f-4e7d-bd3c-e62fe4bbaa4f",
      "_type": "Race",
      "name": "Vice Chairperson",
      "rank": 2,
      "_id": 19,
      "isa_candidate": [
        {
          "member_id": "f584d4a3-1c7d-456f-a798-f6f399a3fa2b",
          "role": "admin",
          "isa_candidate.createdAt": "2022-06-28",
          "created": "2022-06-12",
          "_type": "Member",
          "last_name": "Hendricks-White",
          "telephone": "8765999644",
          "middle_name": "Karon Marie",
          "trn": "105264733",
          "assocition": "Hill Top Primary",
          "isa_candidate.url": "/assets/manifestos/f584d4a3-1c7d-456f-a798-f6f399a3fa2b-256c2ac2-114f-4e7d-bd3c-e62fe4bbaa4f.pdf",
          "isa_candidate.certified": true,
          "member_status": "full",
          "how_paid": "MOE",
          "paid_up": true,
          "_id": 1136,
          "category": "full",
          "isa_candidate.manifesto_summary": "This is my Summary...",
          "first_name": "Jacqueline",
          "email": "jacquelinehendricks4@gmail.com",
          "status": "active"
        },
        {
          "member_id": "20473b78-3344-4d7a-885c-888e70a2585c",
          "role": "admin",
          "isa_candidate.createdAt": "2022-06-28",
          "created": "2022-06-12",
          "_type": "Member",
          "last_name": "Nash",
          "telephone": "8768748162",
          "middle_name": "R",
          "trn": "104804351",
          "assocition": "Hill Top Primary",
          "isa_candidate.url": "/assets/manifestos/20473b78-3344-4d7a-885c-888e70a2585c-256c2ac2-114f-4e7d-bd3c-e62fe4bbaa4f.pdf",
          "isa_candidate.certified": true,
          "member_status": "full",
          "how_paid": "Bursar Paid",
          "paid_up": true,
          "_id": 1150,
          "category": "full",
          "isa_candidate.manifesto_summary": "This is my Summary...",
          "first_name": "Leaon",
          "email": "Jtapr2236@gmail.com",
          "status": "active"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "content": "This is a special election....",
  "nomination_start": "2022-05-15",
  "election_stop_time": "17:15:00-04:00",
  "races": [
    "Chairperson",
    "Vice Chairperson"
  ],
  "election_end_date": "2022-06-10T00:15:00[America/New_York]",
  "name": "JTA Parish Executive 2022",
  "election_id": "2be432d6-1e72-490c-9318-f75d7d3b68c3",
  "audit_authorization": [
    "General Secretary"
  ],
  "_id": 17,
  "elegibility": "full,retired",
  "nominate_authorization": [
    "General Secretary"
  ],
  "campaign_start": "2022-05-30",
  "election_start_date": "2022-05-10T00:15:00[America/New_York]",
  "tally_authorization": [
    "General Secretary"
  ]
}
```

I need to access the properties of the nested arrays 'of_election' and 'isa_candidate'.  I can do

```
RETURN value.of_election
```

but I can't get access to none of its properties. So

```
RETURN value.of_election.name
```

violates all sorts of list/map rules.

How can I access the properties of the nested arrays?

Comment: You can unwind the array and then access the properties, would that work, like this: 
`UNWIND value.of_election as election`

Comment: perfect....you can add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unwind the array as `UNWIND value.of_election as election` and then access the map properties.